# Nokogiri equivalent of Hpricot's html method

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, hpricot

Hpricot's `html` method spits out just the HTML in the document:

```
> Hpricot('<p>a</p>').html
=> "<p>a</p>"
```

By contrast, the closest I can come with Nokogiri is the `inner_html` method, which wraps its output in `<html>` and `<body>` tags:

```
> Nokogiri.HTML('<p>a</p>').inner_html
=> "<html><body><p>a</p></body></html>"
```

How can I get the behavior of Hpricot's `html` method with Nokogiri? I.e., I want this:

```
> Nokogiri.HTML('<p>a</p>').some_method_i_dont_know_about
=> "<p>a</p>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
require 'nokogiri'

puts Nokogiri.HTML('<p>a</p>').to_html #
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body><p>a</p></body></html>
```

If you don't want Nokogiri to create a HTML document, then you can tell it to parse it as a document fragment:

```
puts Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse('<p>a</p>').to_html
# >> <p>a</p>
```

In either case, the `to_html` method returns the HTML version of the document.

Comment: Maybe you jumped the gun with your comment?

Comment: Yup, sorry. This looks like the best solution. `Nokogiri.HTML` occasionally does other weird stuff like wrap fragment in a `<p>` (e.g., `Nokogiri::HTML("a\nb").inner_html`), so it's best to avoid it altogether. Is `Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment` equivalent to the `Hpricot` method?

Comment: "Is Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment equivalent to the Hpricot method?" It is if you want Nokogiri to return a fragment only. Nokogiri tries to help you out by giving you valid HTML, which is what `Nokogiri::HTML(...)` will return.

Answer (score 2):

```
> Nokogiri.HTML('<p>a</p>').xpath('/html/body').inner_html
=> "<p>a</p>"
```

Comment: The CSS equivalent of which is `Nokogiri.HTML('<p>a</p>').at('body').inner_html`. Solves my problem, but it's pretty nasty-looking, no? Is there a way of telling `Nokogiri.HTML` that I don't want it to create a whole document for me? I.e., I don't want Nokogiri.HTML('<p>a</p>').children to include a body tag either

Comment: Sure, I was wondering about `DocumentFragment` but I had never used it. I guess I should have looked it up before typing. :-)

Comment: Aaron Peterson taught me about `DocumentFragment` about two years ago. Since then I've had to use it only a few times. I prefer the more generic `Nokogiri::HTML` because it renders a correct document, but sometimes having the snippet is OK.